# Groovy Sql to get the max value from a column

Tags: sql, groovy

I have the following Groovy code to return the max value from the 'id' column from the 'topic' table:

```
 def rs = sql.executeQuery("select max(id) from topic")

 def maxId = rs.getLong(1)
```

It doesn't work, I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:209)...

Does any one know what the correct code is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it would be easier if you'd use the method `firstRow`. You can either get the value from the result object by name or by index.

by name:

```
def row = sql.firstRow("select max(id) as max from topic")
def maxId = row.max
```

by index:

```
def row = sql.firstRow("select max(id) from topic")
def maxId = row[0]
```

Comment: `row.max` didn't work for me, I get `Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: max for class: groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult
 at groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult.getProperty(GroovyRowResult.java:64)`

Answer (score 1):

Nobody seems to have mentioned that the index in `rs.getLong(1)` is out of bounds. **Getting** fields uses a starting index of 0. **Binding** fields uses a starting index of 1. Why? Historical SQL behaviour.